# Как можно вывести в TextBox только string элементы?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. На C# из сервера получаю данные и эти данные загоняю в `ArrayList`. Потом из этого `ArrayList` нужно вывести в текстбоксе только один элемент `ArrayList`-а. Каждый раз в `ArrayList` попадает только одна строка из сервера и в этой строке есть данные, у которых типы разные, и `integer` и `string` есть. Скажите, как можно только соответствующие стринговыe элементы вывести в текстбоксе?

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = new ArrayList(){
    42, "First String", "Second String", new Random()
};

array.OfType<String>().FirstOrDefault(); // First String
```

- [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx)
- [.OfType<T>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb360913.aspx)
- [.FirstOrDefault<T>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb340482.aspx)

Comment: Опередили меня :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод `Enumerable.OfType<TResult>`.

Подробнее:
[Enumerable.OfType<TResult>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb360913.aspx)

Comment: Программа работает но в текстбоксе ничего нет..

Comment: Можно код?

Comment: ArrayList data = dal.Serched(nameMan);
                IEnumerable<string> query1 = data.OfType<string>();
                foreach (string c in query1)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = c;
                }

Comment: var data = new System.Collections.ArrayList() { 42, "First String", "Second String", new Random() };
var query1 = data.OfType<string>(); 
foreach (string c in query1) { textBox1.Text +=c; }
------
Только что проверил этот код - все работает. Проверьте, что попадает в переменную data у Вас в коде. Может быть там нет String-данных?

Comment: в data_е показывается Count = 1, _values {object[24]}, а может проблема и за того, что из сервера вытаскиваю данные? там nvarchar стоит

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread575645.html
Вот здесь подобная проблема. Вам нужно в коде получения записей из БД на сервере приводить их к типу string, а потом только записывать в ArrayList.

Comment: Спасибо Вам.